# How do reduce tuples into tuple of tuples in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have RDD with rows of type

```
(a,(b,c,d))
(a,(e,f,g))
```

I am trying to reduce it by key such that it yields rows of type

```
(a,(b,c,d),(e,f,g)).
```

But I am getting an error while using this :

```
val redcd = mapd.reduceByKey((_,_))
```

How do I do it?

Comment: what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `RDD` as

```
scala> mapd.foreach(println)
(a,(b,c,d))
(a,(e,f,g))
(b,(b,c,d))
```

Then doing

```
val redcd = mapd.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(x => x.map(_._2).toList)
```

would give you

```
scala> redcd.foreach(println)
(b,List((b,c,d)))
(a,List((b,c,d), (e,f,g)))
```

Now if you want it in the format explained in question you can do

```
val redcd = mapd.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(x => x.map(_._2).toList.mkString(", "))
```

which would generate

```
scala> redcd.foreach(println)
(a,(b,c,d), (e,f,g))
(b,(b,c,d))
```

I hope the answer is helpful